# What is the thinking behind the daily reputation cap?

Tags: discussion, reputation

What is the thinking behind the daily reputation cap? What harm is thus prevented?

If my answer gets 20 upvotes today and 20 tomorrow, why is that twice as good as getting 40 upvotes today?

Comment: If you want any decent feedback on this question you will probably have better luck on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: I also think longevity is a better quality for knowledge than a temporary burst of attention

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question was discussed in detail on MSO [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap)

To summarise:

- To prevent gaming
- To level the playing field